# code igniter delete data from different model using single query

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-datamapper

[i want to delete data from two table using two models but cant do . am using following code .help me to fix this problem]

```
public function delete_all_info_employee($id) {
        // ************* Delete into Employee Table 
        $this->employee_model->_table_name = "tbl_employee"; // table name
        $this->employee_model->_primary_key = "employee_id"; // $id
        $this->employee_model->delete($id);
 $this->expense_model->_table_name = "tbl_expense"; // table name
        $this->expense_model->_primary_key = "expense_id"; // $id
        $this->expense_model->delete($id);
    $type = "success";}
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you cant do? Going by the small samples of code you have provided and assuming your models are correct ( although your usage would indicate a general model be used instead of two ) it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st check you already loaded database in codeigniter\application\config\autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

your method of model

```
public function delete_all_info_employee($id) {
    // ************* Delete into Employee Table 
    $this->db->where('employee_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_employee');

    $this->db->where('expense_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_expense');
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: Well that's a good simple purpose built answer using one model and one call.